# Ansible get a subset of items from a list

Tags: parsing, ansible, line, stdout

I have a list of output from an MQ command that shows the status of a channel, the stdout_lines of my registered variable is;

'stdout_lines': [u'CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)']}

This out worked OK for what I was intending on doing as I need to display the output of the CHANNEL and STATUS only and could find the values using a combinations of .split(')')[1].split('(')[1] and split(')')[4].split('(')[1] to get values SVRCONN.CHL and RUNNING

I have also been using this task for CLUSTER channel but found it was failing, the reason for this was that there is was an extra field,

'stdout_lines': [u'CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)']}

now i could do a check to see if RQMNAME is in the output and then use a different split, but is there a way that this can be done using a string to find the location in output of STATUS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the work from Vladimir i have managed to code what i required by capturing all the fields, irrespective if the number of field in the output
Taking the example of the two channel types above i now have a list of dicts using the code above but instead of debug out i have added it to a status list;

```
 - name: Set status
    set_fact:
      status: "{{status|default([]) + [cooked]}}" 
    with_items: "{{lines}}"
    vars:
      _items: "{{ item.split()|
                  map('regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1')|
                  list }}"
      _cooked: |
        {% for i in _items %}
        {% set arr = i.split() %}
        {{ arr.0 }}: {{ arr.1 }}
        {% endfor %}
      cooked: "{{ _cooked|from_yaml }}"
```

This now gives...
"status       [{'CHLTYPE': u'SVRCONN', 'STATUS': u'RUNNING', 'CONNAME': u'1.2.3.4', 'SUBSTATE': u'RECEIVE', 'CHANNEL': u'SVRCONN.CHL'},
{'STATUS': u'RUNNING', 'CONNAME': u'2.3.4.5', 'SUBSTATE': u'RECEIVE', 'CHLTYPE': u'CLUSRCVR', 'RQMNAME': u'CLUS00', 'CHANNEL': u'CLUSTER_CHL'}]"

now all i need to do is debug output the required field using a single statement

```
  - debug:
      msg: "CHANNEL = {{item.CHANNEL}} STATUS = {{item.STATUS}}{%if (item.RQMNAME is defined) %} QMGR = {{item.RQMNAME}}{%endif%}"
    with_items: "{{status}}"
```

this outputs
"CHANNEL = SVRCONN.CHL STATUS = RUNNING"
"CHANNEL = CLUSTER_CHL STATUS = RUNNING QMGR = CLUS00"

Comment: I have now come across another issue, the above output from the MQ CHSTATUS command now works, however i require to do similar with the MQ CHANNEL command which has a field called DESC, this can have spaces in it; CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DESC(SVRCONN CHANNEL) and the split in the _cooked variable fails. There are 2 options; code around this issue, which i am looking at OR remove the DESC field as for this project i do not need it

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to convert it to real structured data, and you can then access any value that you need. The following is a somewhat hacky way to achieve that, but works:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cooked.CHANNEL }} / {{ cooked.STATUS }}"
      vars:
        cooked: "{{ dict(item | split | map('regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1') | map('split')) }}"
      loop:
        - 'CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'
        - 'CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'
```

To parse this into a dictionary we split on whitespace, convert each `key(value)` into `key value`, split on whitespace again to separate keys from values, then pass that into `dict()`.

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)) => {
    "msg": "SVRCONN.CHL / RUNNING"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)) => {
    "msg": "CLUSTER_CHL / RUNNING"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the list

```yaml
lines:
  - CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
  - CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
```

You can create the list of dictionaries without iteration. For example,

```yaml
cooked: "{{ lines|map('split')|
                  map('map', 'regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1')|
                  map('map', 'split')|
                  map('community.general.dict')|
                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cooked:
  - CHANNEL: SVRCONN.CHL
    CHLTYPE: SVRCONN
    CONNAME: 1.2.3.4
    STATUS: RUNNING
    SUBSTATE: RECEIVE
  - CHANNEL: CLUSTER_CHL
    CHLTYPE: CLUSRCVR
    CONNAME: 2.3.4.5
    RQMNAME: CLUS00
    STATUS: RUNNING
    SUBSTATE: RECEIVE
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    lines:
      - 'CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'
      - 'CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'

    cooked: "{{ lines|map('split')|
                      map('map', 'regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1')|
                      map('map', 'split')|
                      map('community.general.dict')|
                      list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: cooked
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.CHANNEL }} / {{ item.STATUS }}"
      loop: "{{ cooked }}"
```

---

**No filter named 'split' using Ansible 2.3**

In this case, you can use the *split* method. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    lines:
      - 'CHANNEL(SVRCONN.CHL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) CONNAME(1.2.3.4) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'
      - 'CHANNEL(CLUSTER_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) CONNAME(2.3.4.5) RQMNAME(CLUS00) STATUS(RUNNING) SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cooked.CHANNEL }} / {{ cooked.STATUS }}"
      loop: "{{ lines }}"
      vars:
        _items: "{{ item.split()|
                    map('regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1')|
                    list }}"
        _cooked: |
          {% for i in _items %}
          {% set arr = i.split() %}
          {{ arr.0 }}: {{ arr.1 }}
          {% endfor %}
        cooked: "{{ _cooked|from_yaml }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: SVRCONN.CHL / RUNNING
  msg: CLUSTER_CHL / RUNNING
```

---

**2 versions of the command**

Output for:

- SVRCON channel requires values CHANNEL/STATUS and
- CLUSRCVR channel requires values CHANNEL/STATUS/RQMNAME

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: cmd
      loop: "{{ lines }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ cooked.CHLTYPE }}"
      vars:
        _items: "{{ item.split()|
                    map('regex_replace', '\\((.+)\\)$', ' \\1')|
                    list }}"
        _cooked: |
          {% for i in _items %}
          {% set arr = i.split() %}
          {{ arr.0 }}: {{ arr.1 }}
          {% endfor %}
        cooked: "{{ _cooked|from_yaml }}"
        cmd: |
          {% if cooked.CHLTYPE == 'SVRCONN' %}
          {{ cooked.CHANNEL }} / {{ cooked.STATUS }}
          {% elif cooked.CHLTYPE == 'CLUSRCVR' %}
          {{ cooked.CHANNEL }} / {{ cooked.STATUS }} / {{ cooked.RQMNAME }}
          {% endif %}
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=SVRCONN) => 
  cmd: |-
    SVRCONN.CHL / RUNNING
ok: [localhost] => (item=CLUSRCVR) => 
  cmd: |-
    CLUSTER_CHL / RUNNING / CLUS00
```

Comment: tried this but got a failure;
TemplateRuntimeError: {{ lines|map('split')| map('map', 'regex_replace', '\((.+)\)$', ' \1')| map('map', 'split')| map('dict')| list }}: no filter named 'split'
using ansible 2.3.0.0 and
 python version = 2.7.5

Comment: i have tried the following to change the structure
- set_fact:
          status: "{{status|default([]) + [item.replace('(',': ').replace(') ','%').split('%')] }}"
the output from this then becomes
[[u'CHANNEL: SVRCONN.CHL',
  u'CHLTYPE: SVRCONN',
  u'CONNAME: 1.2.3.4',
  u'STATUS: RUNNING',
  u'SUBSTATE: RECEIVE)'
and i need it to be more like 
[u'CHANNEL: SVRCONN.CHL, CHLTYPE: SVRCONN, CONNAME: 1.2.3.4, STATUS: RUNNING, SUBSTATE: RECEIVE'
only able to add the SVRCONN details due to editing space

Comment: I added an example using the *split* method only.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your quick response and although this does work for the requirements i stated it does not work 100% . The reason my initial attempt failed was due to there being an extra field CLUSRCVR channels and split by index was picking up the wrong field.
I really require a dictionary that i can use to obtain values, my output for a SVRCON channel would require values CHANNEL/STATUS and CLUSRCVR would need CHANNEL/STATUS/RQMNAME. Using inline variables means i need to determine if the field exists before i display it and so there would need to at least 2 versions of the command

Comment: You're welcome. I added an example. Anything else?